# Ajuda com lógica de um sistema que grava dados em colunas do Excel

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Galera tenho uma aplicação e consigo passar os dados tranquilo pro excel, o problema surgiu agora pois tenho que fazer um laço e não estou conseguindo achar a melhor maneira para isso. Tenho vários lotes, por exemplo, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. Cada lote tem vários clientes, vamos supor que o lote 1 tenha 2 clientes, e o lote 2 tem 4 clientes. O que eu quero fazer basicamente é listar assim:

```
Numero do lote 1:
Diego
Bruno

Numero do lote 2:
Rafael
Carlos
Ana
Tiago
```

Eu estou fazendo o laço assim, porém ele sempre repete todos em todas as celulas do excel, e fica assim:

```
Numero do lote 1:
Rafael
Carlos
Ana
Tiago

Numero do lote 2:
Rafael
Carlos
Ana
Tiago
```

Esse é o código:

```
 int cont2 = 0;

        //Laço que pega o numero do lote e sempre o repete após os clientes
        for (int r = 0; r < listaGuia.size(); r++) {
            XSSFRow cabRowAnaliticor = sheet1.createRow((cont2 * 1) + 7);
            for (int x = 0; x <= 11; x++) {
                cabRowAnaliticor.createCell(x);
            }
            XSSFCell cellAnaR = cabRowAnaliticor.getCell(0);
            cellAnaR.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
            cellAnaR.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(r).getNumeroLote());

            //Percorre a lista e preenche as celulas
            for (int i = 0; i < listaGuia.size(); i++) {

                XSSFRow cabRowAnalitico7 = sheet1.createRow((cont2 * 1) + 8);
                for (int x = 0; x <= 11; x++) {
                    cabRowAnalitico7.createCell(x);
                }
                System.err.println("Lote no rel: " + listaGuia.get(i).getNumeroLote());

                XSSFCell cellAnaA5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(0);
                cellAnaA5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaA5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getNumeroGuia());

                XSSFCell cellAnaB5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(1);
                cellAnaB5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaB5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getNumeroCarteira());

                XSSFCell cellAnaC5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(2);
                cellAnaC5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaC5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getNomeBeneficiario());

                XSSFCell cellAnaD5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(3);
                cellAnaD5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaD5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getDataRealizacao());

                XSSFCell cellAnaE5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(4);
                cellAnaE5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaE5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getCodServico());

                XSSFCell cellAnaF5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(5);
                cellAnaF5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaF5.setCellValue("Outras Tabelas");

                XSSFCell cellAnaG5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(6);
                cellAnaG5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaG5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getDescServico());

                XSSFCell cellAnaH5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(7);
                cellAnaH5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
                cellAnaH5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getQtdExec());

                XSSFCell cellAnaI5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(8);
                cellAnaI5.setCellStyle(estiloS1);
                cellAnaI5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getFilme());

                XSSFCell cellAnaJ5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(9);
                cellAnaJ5.setCellStyle(estiloS1);
                cellAnaJ5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getValorServico());

                XSSFCell cellAnaK5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(10);
                cellAnaK5.setCellStyle(estiloS1);
                cellAnaK5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getHonorario());

                if (listaGuia.get(i).getTipoGlosa() != null) {
                    XSSFCell cellAnaL5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(11);
                    cellAnaL5.setCellStyle(estiloS1);
                    float xxx = 0f;
                    cellAnaL5.setCellValue(xxx);
                } else {
                    XSSFCell cellAnaL5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(11);
                    cellAnaL5.setCellStyle(estiloS1);
                    cellAnaL5.setCellValue(listaGuia.get(i).getValor());
                }
                cont2++;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Em qual coluna esta o campo lote? Seu FOR não checa se determinado cliente está em um lote, então ele adiciona todos em todos os lotes. Adicione um IF para saber se o cliente X esta no lote Y.

Comment: Diego, o problema é que você percorre a mesma lista duas vezes. Você precisa de duas listas, uma só com os lotes e outras com as guias/nomes.

Comment: Entendo, dai no primeiro FOR eu uso a lista dos lotes?

Comment: Celso, esse é o problema estou pensando em como posso verificar isso.